# Yii different model value displayed in cgridview and views

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have values that are stored in raw number form percents (e.g .998) in my generated models.

However, for my views, as well as display in CGRIDview I would like these data points to be multiplied by 100, but retain the same value in the backend database. So in my view the above example should display as 99.8 %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your CGridView columns the following method:

```
 'columns' => array(
     // ... fields
     array(
         'name' => 'fieldWithPecent',
         'value' => 'sprintf("%3.1f%%", $data->fieldWithPecent * 100)',
     ),
     // other fields definition
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the cgridview ! However, I cannot seem to get this to work for the CDetailView with the same method. Is there some change that needs to be made? Instead it just prints ...  'sprintf("%3.1f%%", $data->fieldWithPecent * 100 next to the label

Comment: For CDetailView, the value doesn't get evaluated, so just remove your quotes around the expression and things should work

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).  In your view, the code might be something like this:

```
$a = .998;
print sprintf('%3.1f%%', $a*100);
```